# SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected comma in JSX React/TypeScript Context Provider

Tags: typescript, react-native, syntax-error, 2d-context-api

I'm facing a SyntaxError while trying to use a Context Provider in my React TypeScript app. The error specifically mentions an unexpected token and an expectation for a comma in the JSX.
`

```
export const MapProvider: React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren<{}>> = ({ children }) => {
    // ... 

    return (
        <MapContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            {children}
        </MapContext.Provider>
    );
};
`
```

I've checked my code for syntax errors, ensured proper placement of brackets and commas in the JSX return statement, reviewed the context initialization and provider setup, and attempted to find similar issues in online forums.

The Error
`
Android Bundling failed 44ms

```
error: SyntaxError: /home/Workspace/Mobile_App/context/MapContext.ts: Unexpected token, expected "," (96:19)

  94 |
  95 |     return (
> 96 |         <MapContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
     |                    ^
  97 |             {children}
  98 |         </MapContext.Provider>
  99 |     )
```

`

Comment: I don't use TS extensively, but I've used .tsx files in the past instead of .jsx files. That may be issue.

Comment: Yeah, it was a file extension issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To use TypeScript with React, use .tsx file extension for components. This tells TypeScript compiler to expect JSX syntax for HTML-like code in JavaScript, providing type checking and other benefits for React development.

You also need to setup your tsconfig with jsx

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html

Comment: It was simply a file extension issue as you mentioned. Thank you.